# could not locate Android SDK path in visual studio enterprise 2015

Tags: xamarin

1. Installed v 2015 enterprise edition.
2. Downloaded JDK ver 9.1 version for 64 bit.
3. Have files in this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\` for Android SDK.

Even after added that SDK path, it shows build a error as

> Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please install it or set Android SDK path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu.

Screeshot for adding sdk and JDK:

[image: screeshot for adding sdk and JDK in VS 2015]

Comment: Can you inspect your Android SDK and ensure that you have all the folders inside(build-tools, platform-tools, tools, etc)? I have a feeling that your local install could've got messed up. Can you try to re-download the Android SDK?

Comment: i didnt install Android sdk seperately, after VS 2015 installation, have got a file and folders for android sdk,

Comment: jus let me know, how to locate proper SDK location, n how to install sdk seperately